# Printing from Ionic 2 application not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, printing, ionic2, ionic-native

I have the following code in `people.ts`:

```
export class People {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private printer: Printer) {}

  public Printyo(){
    console.log("in the printyo method");
    this.printer.isAvailable();
    let options: PrintOptions = {
     name: 'MyDocument',
     printerId: 'GuestPrint_iLab',
     duplex: true,
     landscape: true,
     grayscale: true
    };
    this.printer.print("yolo", options);
  }

}
```

and in `people.html` I have:

```
<ion-card (click)="Printyo()">
    <img src="assets/images/print.jpg"/>
    <div class="card-title">Print</div>
</ion-card>
```

I am trying to make it so that if you click on the `ion-card`, the Printyo method is called and the string `yolo` is sent to the printer.  When I run this in the IOS emulator, I receive the following output: `[app-scripts] [11:42:13]  console.log: in the printyo method` but nothing is printed.  There is no error. I'm pretty sure this is because I am not correctly setting the `printerId` option but I'm not sure how to correctly set it. I've tried going to `http://localhost:631/printers` to find the printer location, but for this printer, the location field is blank, even though I know I'm attached to the printer because I have no issue printing from this computer.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `Promise` returned from `isAvailable`? That will indicate you whether the device is capable of printing. Once that is true, then you can proceed to print. Also, the `print` [method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer/#print) accepts a `string` only if it's a **URL** , otherwise you would need to pass an *[HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)* from which it's `[innerHTML][2]` method would be called.

Comment: The logs are blank. It's not showing isAvailable as returning anything.

Comment: `isAvailable()` returns a `Promise<boolean>` , so you would need to do something like `this.printer.isAvailable().then(available => console.log('is it available', available));`